# Insert new line dynamically into a Table context, using Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, html-table, handlebars.js

I'm new to Ember and Handlebars.
I am trying to create a table with a dynamic content.
I add the code into  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgyAk/)

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<table border="1" bordercolor="FFCC00" style="background-color:FFFFCC" width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
  {{#each Table.tableController}}
  <tbody>
<tr>
    <td width ="30%">{{title}}</td>
    <td width ="30%">{{artist}}</td>
            <td width ="40%">{{genre}}</td>
</tr>
   </tbody>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

A simple table binding a content from my controller.

And here is my controller and application:

```
Table = Ember.Application.create({});

Table.Cell = Ember.Object.extend({
title: null,
artist: null,
genre: null,
listens: 0
});

Table.tableController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
content: [],
init: function() {
    var data = Table.Cell.create({
    title: 'Ruby',
    artist: 'Kaiser Chiefs',
    genre: 'Indie Rock',
        });
    this.pushObject(data);
    data = Table.Cell.create({
    title: 'Somebody Told Me',
    artist: 'Killers',
    genre: 'Indie Rock',
        });
        this.pushObject(data);
    },
    createSong: function(title, artist, genre) {
    var cell = Table.Cell.create({
    title: title,
    artist: artist,
    genre: genre,
        });
    this.pushObject(cell);
    },
});
```

That's working just fine.

Now I want to add a new song, and I am doing this via Chrome console with the following line:

```
 Table.tableController.createSong('Feiticeira', 'Deftones', 'Alternative');
```

I can verify that a new Object is created and inserted into my content array.
But there is no changes into my table.

What am I doing wrong?
Why my table is not creating a new content?

I pushed this code into jsfiddle to get help you help me. 
  [Here's the link to the code again.](http://jsfiddle.net/AgyAk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED ANALYSIS**

You forgot calling `this._super();` in the `init`, which prevented your instance to have its binding management setup. ([Fixed revision](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/AgyAk/11/))

<del>You felt in a typical Ember gotcha: initial values should never be objects, as they would be shared by all class instances... See [this article](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/) for more informations.</del>

**FIX SAMPLE - *Still recommended implementation***

Updated your JSFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/AgyAk/12/ with a few improvements *(The most notable: make use of a controller rather than directly `ArrayProxy`. It is more idiomatic and ready to switch to `Router` infrastructure)*.